# How to create dynamic lists in 11ty static site generator?

Tags: eleventy

I'm creating a new website, and I want to be able to edit my content using Vim.  That means I should probably be using a static site generator - right? I've been using Drupal for the last ten years, but since I don't need to give clients a gui to edit their content, I'm considering a different technology.

11ty looks like a decently simple static site generator, and the ability to type my content in markdown in Vim, run a simple command, git commit and push to publish the content is very appealing.

But I'm wondering about more dynamic/automated content... like in Drupal there are "views" which are SQL queries (and can be quite complex, it provides a gui for building them and formatting their results) for displaying recent posts, upcoming events, etc.  How do you create such elements in 11ty?  Can 11ty alone do it?  Would you have to utilize something like vue.js with 11ty to do this?

I'd be open to using a different static site generator (I'm even considering using Drupal and posting to the site's Rest API) but I don't want to deal with reactjs.

Answer (score 3):

The heart and soul of processing "data" in 11ty is putting things into `.json` or `.js` files that export a JavaScript object into the `_data` folder of your project.

Let's say you have a file in there called `kittens.js` like this:

```js
const kittens = [
 {
  name: 'Oreo',
  colors: ['black','white'],
  slug: 'oreo'
 },
 {
  name: 'Hershey',
  colors: ['brown'],
  slug: 'hershey'
 }
];

module.exports = () => {
  return kittens;
};
```

The keyword **`kittens`** is now a special keyword as far as 11ty template files capable of having a "page" context is concerned.

It contains the nested-object-structured information about Oreo and Hershey.

All you have to do is pick a templating language and loop through it.

For example, you could put a file into your project's main folder called, say, `loop_kittens.liquid` like this, and 11ty would pick it up as something from which it's supposed to generate HTML:

```
---
layout: "layouts/my_base"
pagination:
  alias: documentData
  data: kittens
  size: 1
  addAllPagesToCollections: true
permalink: /kitten/{{ documentData.slug }}/index.html
---

<h1>{{documentData.name}}</h1>
<ul>
  {% for color in documentData.colors %}
    <li>color</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**I'm not familiar with Drupal, but the #1 thing you're going to have to deal with in coming from any declarative SQL-based *(table-shaped)* system and moving into an imperative nested-lists-and-objects-shape-based system is thinking about looping through data and selecting it differently.**

You may even want to preprocess your raw data in those `_data`-folder files so that it gets exported to **`kittens`** in a way that's optimized for rather traditional manual for-looping *(although the "pagination" properties of a template with size set to 1 can definitely help hide the complexities of dividing up a dataset into individual HTML pages that need generation)*.

11ty pagination can also "chunk" your dataset so that you only have to worry about hand-looping through a given subchunk of `kittens` on any given page *(e.g. the "kitten archives," with 10 kittens per archive page)*.

But as far as actually putting a block for each kitten on each of those pages -- that's going to be a manual for-loop in your template, whichever templating language you choose.  *(I've found that Liquid strikes a nice balance between simplicity and being able to delegate things in each pass of a for loop to an "include," so as to maintain modular, componentized code -- see "[dynamic partials](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/liquid/)".)*

I recommend making your own dummy data like I just did and practicing using all of 11ty's many templating, layout, component-include, etc. options on a practice site before you start trying to do a real project.  11ty isn't a very opinionated framework, so it's nice to pick your own favorite way of organizing it and learning about its magic-folder naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks! That's a helpful start... but how do my pages (composed in markdown in `.md` files) related to these `.js` data files and the `_data` folder?

Comment: @alec I'd envisioned them _**instead**_ of having a bunch of `.md` files.  But it turns out you can also put special `.11tydata.js` and `11tydata.json` files in the folders containing `.md` files as a sort of "here're some properties these all have in common" add-on, if needed.  Okay, so ... if you have `/kittens/oreo.md` and `/kittens/hershey.md` and you just wanted, like, a `<ul>` w/ their names on each `<li>`, you'd just ... write an include such as `/_includes/quick_kitten_list.liquid` that read something like `<ul>{% for kitten in kittens %}<li>{{ kitten.name }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>`.

Comment: Because 11ty is natively going to take care of generating URLs out of `.md` files in folders -- you have to muck with it to get it to stop.  @alec, if you wanted to do something sort of secondary auto-URL generation _(e.g. `/kitten_archives/1`, `/kitten_archives/2`...)_ against `.md`-based data such as `kittens`, that's more where doing something like my original pattern might make sense.  That said, I can't remember, but the syntax is something more like `collections.all.kittens` for the one 11ty builds out of your `/kittens/*.md` folder, but just `kittens` for `_data` or something.

Comment: Gaah -- uneditable comment. @alec I'd envisioned them _**instead**_ of having a bunch of `.md` files. With `/kittens/oreo.md` & `/kittens/hershey.md` if you wanted a `<ul>` w/ their names on each `<li>`, you'd just ... write an include such as `/_includes/quick_kitten_list.liquid` that read something like `<ul>{% for kitten in kittens %}<li>{{ kitten.name }}</li>{% endfor %}</ul>`.

Also, FYI...if needed for changing, say, 11ty's default "permalink" for `/kittens/*.md`, you can add `/kittens/kittens.11tydata.js` and/or `/kittens/kittens11tydata.json` files rather than redundant front matter.